# Rails minify/optimize files on the fly using Grunt or Gulp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gruntjs, gulp, sidekiq

My Rails 4 application allow it's users to import some Adobe Edge animation files (advertisement). While it works, Adobe Edge is loading a bunch of files that could be minified and optimized (images) using a tool like Grunt or Gulp.

I'm using CarrierWave to upload the files and then I extract them if they are inside an archive :

```
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  after :store, :uncompress_and_update_reference

  def uncompress_and_update_reference(_file)
    return unless archive_is_supported?(model.ext)
    extractor = Uploader::Archive.const_get("Extractor#{model.ext.upcase}").new
    Uploader::Archive::PubArchive.new(extractor, model, full_path).extract_and_save
  end
end
```

I was thinking that I could use Grunt or Gulp in a background job (using Sidekiq for example) to work on those extracted files as I need. The problem is how can I do it?

From what I've read, in order to run `grunt` or `gulp`, they both need to have a `Gruntfile.js` and `Gulpfile.js` respectively, which makes things tricky as I need to run it dynamically inside the extracted folder.

Anyone?

Comment: You can easily pass command line arguments to both Grunt and Gulp though `process.argv`.

Comment: Ok thanks, didn't know that. Since Grunt / Gulp needs a config file in order to run, how can I run the command `grunt` or `gulp` and using a common external file? Their API don't seems to show how to achieve it as it assume that the config file is always in the current folder.

Comment: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/pass-arguments-from-cli.md

Comment: Could a gem like `htmlcompressor` help? https://github.com/paolochiodi/htmlcompressor

Comment: @kobaltz. I've check that gem but unfortunately my case require a lot of custom treatment only tool like Grunt or Gulp can achieve. I'm starting to build a node CLI that will achieve that. That is the easiest solution I've found so far. Will write a post here as soon as I have something that work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally created a Node CLI to handle that case. Since I needed to be able to optimize files dynamically inside a folder, having a command line utility is somehow the best scenario :

**cli.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

'use strict';

var meow      = require('meow');
var fs        = require('fs');
var optimizer = require('./');

var cli = meow({
  help: [
    'Usage : pub-optimizer <path_to_optimize> <path_to_optimize>',
    ''
  ].join('\n')
});

var paths = cli.input

paths.forEach(function (path) {
  if (fs.existsSync(path) {
    optimizer.minify(path);
  } else {
    console.log(path + ' is not a valid directory.')
  }
});
```

**index.js**

```
'use strict';

var gulp     = require('gulp');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant');

exports.minify = function (folderPath) {

  // Remove trailing slash
  folderPath = folderPath.replace(/\/+$/, "");

  // Optimize images
  gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp
      .src(folderPath + '/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}')
      .pipe(imagemin({
        progressive: true,
        use: [pngquant()]
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(folderPath));
  });

  gulp.start();
};
```

Then all I need to do was to invoke that CLI from my Rails app :

**uploaders/file_uploader.rb**

```
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  after :store, :uncompress_and_update_reference

  def uncompress_and_update_reference(_file)
    return unless archive_is_supported?(model.ext)
    extractor = Uploader::Archive.const_get("Extractor#{model.ext.upcase}").new
    Uploader::Archive::PubArchive.new(extractor, model, full_path).extract_and_save

    PubOptimizerWorker.perform_async(fullpath)
  end
end
```

**workers/pub_optimizer_worker.rb**

```
class PubApprovalRequestWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: :pub

  def perform(path)
    system("pub-optimizer #{path}")
  end
end
```

Hope this will maybe help someone.